# Python Opencv drawContours fail when I draw just the bigger contour object

Tags: opencv, contour

I'm trying to draw the contour of the biggest object.

First I will show an image drawing all contours:

[image: All contours objects]

To find the biggest object I used this code:

```
maxsize = 0  
best = 0  
count = 0  
for cnt in contours:  
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > maxsize:  
        maxsize = cv2.contourArea(cnt)  
        best = count  
    count += 1  

cv2.drawContours(img_rgb, contours[best], -1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

And the result is the next:
[image: Contours of biggest object]

Why the contours are not connected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that on your code you are telling by the `-1` parameter to the function draw all of your contours, when you actually wants to draw only the `best` one. So, instead of the `-1` (all) you can simply ask for the function to draw the contour that you desire.

You can fix this problem replacing the line:

```
cv2.drawContours(img_rgb, contours[best], -1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

with:

```
cv2.drawContours(img_rgb, contours, best, (0,0,255), 2)
```

or you can still use the `-1`, but then you are going to need as parameter a set of points (`[]`):

```
cv2.drawContours(img_rgb, [contours[best]], -1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

You can have more information about this theme in the [OpenCV Docs page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html)